# Error when I run a chrome plugin : Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension where keywords are populated in search from MYSQL database

my popup.js :

```
// UI creation
!function() {

    "use strict";

    /*|================================================================|*/
    /*|                          UI creation                           |*/
    /*|================================================================|*/
    var initSectionByBgColorFromTemplate = function (sectionNodeTemplate, bgColorCode, wordGroupsDict) {
        var sectionNode = sectionNodeTemplate.cloneNode(true);
        var handlingIndex = 0;
        var classNames = ["pure-toggle-checkbox", "pure-toggle", "color-header", "remove-group-button", "highlight-words"];

        var toggleCheckbox = sectionNode.getElementsByClassName(classNames[handlingIndex])[0];
        toggleCheckbox.id = classNames[handlingIndex].concat("-", bgColorCode);
        toggleCheckbox.dataset.bgColor = bgColorCode;
        toggleCheckbox.checked = wordGroupsDict[bgColorCode].isOn;
        toggleCheckbox.addEventListener("change", wordGroupToogleHandlerFactory(wordGroupsDict));
        handlingIndex++;

        var toggleLabel = sectionNode.getElementsByClassName(classNames[handlingIndex])[0];
        toggleLabel.id = classNames[handlingIndex].concat("-", bgColorCode);
        toggleLabel.htmlFor = toggleCheckbox.id;
        handlingIndex++;

        var header = sectionNode.getElementsByClassName(classNames[handlingIndex])[0];
        header.style.backgroundColor = "#".concat(bgColorCode);
        header.textContent = bgColorCode;
        handlingIndex++;

        var removeButton = sectionNode.getElementsByClassName(classNames[handlingIndex])[0];
        removeButton.dataset.bgColorCode = bgColorCode;
        removeButton.addEventListener("click", removeGroupHandlerFactory(wordGroupsDict, sectionNode));
        handlingIndex++;

        var textarea = sectionNode.getElementsByClassName(classNames[handlingIndex])[0];
        textarea.id = classNames[handlingIndex].concat("-", bgColorCode);
        textarea.dataset.bgColor = bgColorCode;
        textarea.value = wordGroupsDict[bgColorCode].words.join(" ");
        textarea.addEventListener("blur", wordListChangeHandlerFactory(wordGroupsDict));
        handlingIndex++;

        return sectionNode;
    };

    var mainBlock = document.getElementById("mainBlock");
    var sessionTemplate = mainBlock.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];
    var newGroupForm = document.getElementById("new-group-form");
    var colorInputBox = document.getElementById("new-group-color");

    /*|================================================================|*/
    /*|                 load UI data and event binding                 |*/
    /*|================================================================|*/
    var getDefaultWordGroup = function (groupName) {
        return {
            groupName: groupName,
            isOn: false,
            words: []
        };
    };
    var createNewGroupInDict = function (wordGroupsDict, groupName) {
        var wordGroup = wordGroupsDict[groupName];

        if (!wordGroup) {
            wordGroup = getDefaultWordGroup(groupName);
            wordGroupsDict[groupName] = wordGroup;
        }
    };
    var saveAndSendMsg = function (wordGroupsDict) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            wordGroupsDict: wordGroupsDict
        }, function () {
            // console.log("wordGroupsDict saved");
        });

        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            var messageBody = wordGroupsDict;
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, messageBody, function(response) {
                // console.log(response.content);
            });
        });
    };
    var wordGroupToogleHandlerFactory = function (wordGroupsDict) {
        return function (event) {
            var groupName = event.target.dataset.bgColor;
            var wordGroup = wordGroupsDict[groupName];
            wordGroup.isOn = event.target.checked;

            saveAndSendMsg(wordGroupsDict);
        };
    };
    var wordListChangeHandlerFactory = function (wordGroupsDict) {
        return function (event) {
            var groupName = event.target.dataset.bgColor;
            var wordGroup = wordGroupsDict[groupName];
            wordGroup.words = event.target.value.match(/[^\s]+/g) || [];

            saveAndSendMsg(wordGroupsDict);
        };
    };
    var removeGroupHandlerFactory = function (wordGroupsDict, sectionNode) {
        return function (event) {
            sectionNode.parentElement.removeChild(sectionNode);
            delete wordGroupsDict[event.target.dataset.bgColorCode];

            saveAndSendMsg(wordGroupsDict);
        };
    };

    /*|================================================================|*/
    /*|                    load extension settings                     |*/
    /*|================================================================|*/
    chrome.storage.sync.get('wordGroupsDict', function (wordGroupsDict) {

        // I just dont know how chrome.storage.sync works...
        // + nothing inside, return {}
        // + find the key, return {key: value}
        wordGroupsDict = wordGroupsDict.wordGroupsDict || wordGroupsDict;


        /*|================================================================|*/
        /*|                   popup UI and event binding                   |*/
        /*|================================================================|*/
        // use default for 1st time
        var colorGroups = Object.keys(wordGroupsDict);



        if (colorGroups.length === 0) {
            colorGroups = ["C72E04", "FA9507", "CACF44", "27AB99"].slice(1);
            colorGroups.forEach( colorGroup => createNewGroupInDict(wordGroupsDict, colorGroup) );
        }

    /*  
    if (colorGroups.length === 0) {
        var valNew = [];
            var array = [];
            $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'http://localhost/chrome-highlight-extension-master/js/loadcolor.php',
              data: {
              },
              success: function (response) {
                 var res = $.trim(response);
                 valNew = res.split(',');
                  for(var i=0;i<(valNew.length);i++){
                        colorGroups.push(valNew[i]);
                    }
                 colorGroups.forEach( colorGroup => createNewGroupInDict(wordGroupsDict, colorGroup) );
              }
              }); 
        } */

        // remove template and append initialized sections
        mainBlock.removeChild(sessionTemplate);
        colorGroups.forEach(function (bgc) {
            mainBlock.appendChild(initSectionByBgColorFromTemplate(sessionTemplate, bgc, wordGroupsDict));
        });
        newGroupForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (colorInputBox.value && colorInputBox.value.length > 0 && colorInputBox.checkValidity()) {
                console.log("submit OK");
                createNewGroupInDict(wordGroupsDict, colorInputBox.value);
                mainBlock.appendChild(initSectionByBgColorFromTemplate(sessionTemplate, colorInputBox.value, wordGroupsDict));
            }
            console.log("submit");
        });
        colorInputBox.addEventListener("onload", function (event) {
            if (event.target.checkValidity()) {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#".concat(event.target.value);
            } else {
                event.target.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            }
        });
    });
}();
```

In the above code I have some static colors

```
colorGroups = ["C72E04", "FA9507", "CACF44", "27AB99"];
```

But I want these colors from MYSQL db , so i used ajax to get colors (that part of the code has been commented )

```
 if (colorGroups.length === 0) {
        var valNew = [];
            var array = [];
            $.ajax({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'http://localhost/chrome-highlight-extension-master/js/loadcolor.php',
              data: {
              },
              success: function (response) {
                 var res = $.trim(response);
                 valNew = res.split(',');
                  for(var i=0;i<(valNew.length);i++){
                        colorGroups.push(valNew[i]);
                    }
                 colorGroups.forEach( colorGroup => createNewGroupInDict(wordGroupsDict, colorGroup) );
              }
              }); 
        }
```

In the ajax code i am able to fetch colors from my table but the problem is with createNewGroupInDict

this is the error I am facing

```
Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://pgommpfcheidcagdchjjdhffidaefhaf/js/popup.js:159:16)
    at chrome-extension://pgommpfcheidcagdchjjdhffidaefhaf/js/popup.js:113:22
    at chrome-extension://pgommpfcheidcagdchjjdhffidaefhaf/js/popup.js:176:2
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Keyword Page</title>
    <link href="css/popup.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/toggle.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <main id="mainBlock">
        <div class="button-block"> 
            <form id="new-group-form"> 
                 <input id="new-group-color" type="text" pattern="[0-9a-fA-f]{6}" title="hex color code" /> 
                <input id="add-button" class="button" type="submit" value="+" title="add group" /> 
             </form>
         </div> 
        <section>
            <span class="toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" class="pure-toggle-checkbox" hidden />
                <label class="pure-toggle flip" for="pure-toggle-">
                    <div class="fontawesome-remove">OFF</div>
                    <div class="fontawesome-ok">ON</div>
                </label>
            </span>
            <header class="color-header">C72E04</header>
            <button class="remove-group-button button">x</button>
            <textarea class="highlight-words" placeholder="(separated by a space)" > </textarea>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Line 159 appears to be `newGroupForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {`, initialized in `var newGroupForm = document.getElementById("new-group-form");`. Are you sure #new-group-form exists in your HTML?

Comment: yes my popup.html has  #new-group-form

Comment: try moving `var mainBlock = document.getElementById("mainBlock");
    var sessionTemplate = mainBlock.getElementsByTagName("section")[0];
    var newGroupForm = document.getElementById("new-group-form");
    var colorInputBox = document.getElementById("new-group-color");` at the top of js file

Comment: You should also move this `newGroupForm.addEventListener("submit"` outside of `chrome.storage.sync.get('wordGroupsDict` because this will bind multiple `submit` events to your form.

Comment: Don't use form at all. Submitting a form reloads the HTML because that's how forms work - they submit the data and replace the current page with the response.

Comment: Forms are fine for general-purpose data entry; it is quite common to have a form and then `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the submission from reloading the page.

Comment: Yes, with preventDefault forms can be used so this error must have been caused by something else. A typical mistake is including popup.js somewhere else e.g. in content_scripts or in background section of manifest.json, another typical mistake is not using the proper devtools for the popup, which should be invoked by rightclicking the popup and choosing Inspect there.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I have changed most of the code and its working now